# Will 12" tiles crack if laid on a bowed concrete floor?

Tags: tile

Today I laid tile in a 25sq ft bathroom with a concrete subfloor.  The concrete had a slight "bow" to it, meaning if you hold a straight edge across the 5' width, there is a gap of about 1/8" in the center.  The tiles pretty much follow that slight curve.  Will this cause any problems with cracking?
If it matters, the tiles are 12" squares, inexpensive ceramic.

Comment: What kind of load (traffic) do you expect there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah. You are good to go.  Tiles will crack if they bear weight over an unsupported spot. The bow in itself is irrelevant.

Comment: 1/8" (c. 3mm) is small enough that you can even let the thinset mortar be thicker in the center of the room, eliminating the bow with the tile layer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use comb to comb the mortar? The most important is to have the mortar under the whole tile surface. The bow is not a problem then.

[image: Comb the mortar]